# Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) when creating instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've just deployed my app to Heroku and i'm getting a strange error.
Here is my Heroku console session recreating the error:
I've got an Apartment object a:

```
>> a

=> #<Apartment id: 4, general_description: nil, created_at: "2013-11-20 09:00:05", updated_at: "2013-11-20 09:00:05", landlord_id: 1, bills_included: nil, bills: nil, mcl: nil, accomodation_type: nil, num_bathrooms: nil, booked_complete: nil, floor: nil, elevator: nil, size: nil>

>>a.create_address

   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("addressable_id", "addressable_type", "city_id", "created_at", "number", "street", "updated_at", "zipcode") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["addressable_id", 4], ["addressable_type", "Apartment"], ["city_id", nil], ["created_at", Wed, 20 Nov 2013 09:34:42 UTC +00:00], ["number", nil], ["street", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 20 Nov 2013 09:34:42 UTC +00:00], ["zipcode", nil]]
   (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

I know the connection to my DB is working since I was able for example to create a User and sign him in. I have no idea what is the problem with this table..

Also, If I do:

```
>> Address.new
```

I get:

```
=> #<Address id: nil, street: nil, zipcode: nil, number: nil, addressable_id: nil, addressable_type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, city_id: nil>
```

Thanks for every and all help!

**EDIT:**

Address.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number, :street, :zipcode, :city_id
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :city

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  def city_name
    city.name
  end

  def to_s
    "#{street} #{number}, #{city_name}, #{city.country_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Please paste the contents of `Address` class as well as full error backtrace.

Comment: Added in edit. Now that you say it, it very well might have something to do with Tire.. I'll try removing it and see if it solves the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your Elastic search server is not running ,your model is trying to connect to elastic search search. Start your elastic search on production.

If you have not configured elastic search on production then you have to first install it on production server.

Comment: That's it, i feel stupid for not looking in the Model... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this add on 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai
and run

```
heroku run rake tire:import:all
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error since my Elastic search was not running. This is what I did to resolve the issue:

Step 1:
brew info will give you options on how to start elacticsearch

$ brew info elacticsearch

Step 2:
$ elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

Hope this helps.